# How to generate .so file for all architecture from cpp code android

Tags: android, android-ndk

i am using [this](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus) library for live camera filter . I want to generate a `.so` file via Cpp on windows for all architecture `(armeabi-v7a, armeabi,x86,x86_64)` and got `.so` file generate now I have cross compile this .so file for Android ARM so I have to comiple it via Android NDK so that new genrated .so can be used in my android project .

i already have `(armeabi-v7a, armeabi,x86)` this architecture `.so` file, but unable to generate `x86_64` architecture `.so` file , 
So can anyone help me **how to generate .so file for `x86_64` architecture from cpp code**.

I hope my question is clear to you all, if not please tell me.

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: you could read this https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support

Answer (score 1):

If you have an NDK project file **Android.mk** that builds different versions of your **.so**, you only need to specify **`APP_ABI=arm64-v8a`** to get the missing one. If you use some other build system, you need to find the equivalent setting. Note that `armeabi` can probably be dropped, and it is not longer supported by the latest NDK r18.

Comment: This does not belong to Android.mk. You can set it in Application.mk or on command line.

Comment: ohh yes my mistake i add this line in application.mk but still not generate .so for x86_64 architecture

Comment: if you need all four, you are allowed to write `APP_ABI:="amreabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64"`

Comment: ok but i don't know where to fire command for this in windows

Comment: `export NDK=path/of/your/ndk
cd folder/of/jni (android-gpuimage-plus/library/src/main/jni)

#This will make all arch: armeabi, armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a, x86, mips
./buildJNI
#Or use "sh buildJNI"`


where to fire this commands ?

Comment: Where does this `buildJNI` script come from? How do you build the **armeabi-v7a** verison if you cannot run this script?

Comment: i use [this](https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus/) library . this library already have  **armeabi-v7a** `.so` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183933/discussion-between-alex-cohn-and-aanal-shah).

Comment: This script is tuned for Linux, but you can probably run `<full path to>\ndk-build.cmd APP_ABI='armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86 x86_64'` in directory `android-gpuimage-plus\library\src\main`. Note that this will not be done by Android Studio for you, but it will accept the libraries you have build.